# Recursively search directory of binary files for hexadecimal sequence?

Tags: shell, zsh, binaryfiles, hexdump, find-util

The current commands I'm using to search some hex values (say `0A 8b 02`) involve:

`find . -type f -not -name "*.png" -exec xxd -p {} \; | grep "0a8b02" || xargs -0 -P 4`

Is it possible to improve this given the following goals:

- search files recursively
- display the offset and filename
- exclude certain files with certain extensions (above example will not search `.png` files)
- speed: search needs to handle 200,000 files (around 50KB to 1MB) in a directly totaling ~2GB.

I'm not too confident if the `xargs` is working properly for 4 processors. Also I'm having difficulties printing the filename when `grep` finds a match since it is piped from `xxd`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would write a script for grepping a single binary (which prints the filename on success), and use that script in `find | xargs`. You're in zsh so it's hard to define functions in a subshell. If you're determined to have everything in one script, you can use bash instead, which allows you to export a function.

Comment: So given what I currently have... it's impossible to even output the filename?

Comment: There'd be a fairly simple solution if the search byte sequences _never_ included `0xa` (i.e., newlines) - but it sounds like they can, right? Also, are you using _GNU_ utilities (Linux)?

Comment: @mklement0 No, sequences will never include `0xa`, I'm running this on OS X unfortunately. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, probably yes. However, perhaps installing GNU `grep` is an option for you. Have a look at my answer and let's continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF:

- you have *GNU* `grep`
- AND the hex bytes you search for NEVER contain newlines (`0xa`)<sup>[1]</sup>

  - If they contain NUL (`0x`), you must provide the `grep` search string via a file (`-f`) rather than by direct argument.

the following command would get you there, using the example of searching for `0e 8b 02`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -type f -not -name "*.png" -exec grep -FHoab $'\x{0e}\x{8b}\x{02}' {} + |
  LC_ALL=C cut -d: -f1-2
```

The `grep` command produces output lines as follows:

```
<filename>:<byte-offset>:<matched-bytes>
```

which `LC_ALL=C cut -d: -f1-2` then reduces to `<filename>:<byte-offset>`

The command *almost* works with *BSD* `grep`, except that the byte offset reported is invariably the *start* of the line that the pattern was matched on.
In other words: *the byte offset will only be correct if no newlines precede a match in the file*.
Also, BSD `grep` doesn't support specifying NUL (`0x0`) bytes as part of the search string, not even when provided via a file with `-f`.

- Note that there'll be *no* parallel processing, but only a *few* `grep` invocations, based on using `find`'s `-exec ... +`, which, like `xargs`, passes as many filenames as will fit on a command line to `grep` at once.
- By letting `grep` search for the byte sequence directly, there is no need for `xxd`:

  - The sequence is specified as an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), which means that the escape sequences are expanded to literals by the *shell*, enabling Grep to then search for the resulting string *as a literal* (via `-F`), which is faster.
    <sup>The linked article is from the `bash` manual, but they work in `zsh` (and `ksh`) too.</sup>

    - A GNU Grep alternative is to use `-P` (support for PRCEs, Perl-compatible regular expressions) with non-pre-expanded escape sequences, but this will be *slower*: `grep -PHoab '\x{0e}\x{8b}\x{02}'`
  - `LC_ALL=C` ensures that `grep` treats each *byte* as its own character without applying any encoding rules.
  - `-F` treats the search strings as a literal (rather than a regex)
  - `-H` prepends the relevant input filename to each output line; note that Grep does this implicitly when given more than 1 filename argument
  - `-o` only report matched strings (byte sequences), not the whole line (the concept of a line has no meaning in binary files anyway)<sup>[2]</sup>
  - `-a` treats binary files as if they were text files (without this, Grep would only print text `Binary file <filename> matches` for binary input files with matches)
  - `-b` reports the byte offsets of matches

If it's sufficient to find at most *1* match in a given input file, add `-m 1`.

---

<sup>[1] Newlines cannot be used, because Grep invariably treats newlines in a search-pattern string as separating *multiple* search patterns. Also, Grep is *line*-based, so you can't match across lines; GNU Grep's `-null-data` option to split the input by NUL bytes could help, but only if your search byte sequence doesn't also comprise NUL bytes; you'd also have to represent your byte values as *escape sequences* in a *regex* combined with `-P` - because you'll need to use escape sequence `\n` in lieu of actual newlines.</sup>

<sup>[2] `-o` is needed to make `-b` report the byte offset of the *match* as opposed to that of the *beginning of the line* (as stated, BSD Grep *always* does the latter, unfortunately); additionally, it is beneficial to only report the matches themselves here, as an attempt to print the *entire line* would result in unpredictably long output lines, given that there's no concept of lines in binary files; either way, however, outputting bytes from a binary file may cause strange rendering behavior in the terminal.</sup>

Comment: Followed [this blog](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/) on installing GNU `grep`, I'm still having issues: a simple [`ggrep -P`](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5959/grep-binary-hexadecimal-patterns) works, however I couldn't get your command to return anything from a simple search for `00`. I'm open to *any* solution using BSD `grep` if that's possible for you. It doesn't have to be one line, a script works fine for me.

Comment: Just to note homebrew installs gnu grep as `ggrep`. Running `ggrep --version` gives `(GNU grep) 2.21`. Is it also possible to display n bytes ahead/behind of the matched offset?

Comment: @VeraWang: It's a limitation of the _shell_ that you can't pass values that include NUL (`0x0`) as an _argument_. With _GNU_ Grep you can work around that by saving the byte sequence to a _file_ and then using that file with `-f`. Sadly, this technique does _not_ work with _BSD_ Grep.

Comment: @VeraWang: Re displaying n bytes of context: from what I can tell, the context features invariably relate to _lines of text_, not bytes.

Comment: @VeraWang: Here's an example of how to generate a single NUL, which you can redirect to a file: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Tangential question: is there a cleaner way of excluding multiple file extensions? I'm resorting to `! -name "*.ext"` for each one.

Comment: @VeraWang: You can use the `-regex` `-iregex` primaries, which match the entire path against a regular expression (case-insensitively in the latter case). If you combine that with `-E` to enable _extended_ regular expressions, you can use alternation (`|`), such as in the following example, which excludes both `.txt` and `.bak` files: `find -E . ! -iregex '.*\.(bak|txt)$'`